# Microsoft Edge SVG rendering bug

Tags: jquery, svg

I've created hexagonal timer using SVG, which contains of 2 paths: one for core hexagon, and one that fills as the timer counts. Here is working codepen: http://codepen.io/decipher91/pen/rMXYRV/

```
<div class="svg-counter">
    <svg class="counter" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 776 628">
        <path class="track" d="M723 314L543 625.77 183 625.77 3 314 183 2.23 543 2.23 723 314z"></path>
        <path class="fill" d="M723 314L543 625.77 183 625.77 3 314 183 2.23 543 2.23 723 314z"></path>
    </svg>
</div>
```

On all browsers filling starts from top left angle, but on Edge it starts from the bottom right one. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Is Edge choking on `initialOffset` being a string (`var initialOffset = '2160';`)? I see it's being used in calculations for `stroke-dashoffset`. What happens when you change that to be a number?

Comment: @J.Titus Nice try but it doesn't help

Comment: @DavidG - Thanks for testing - I don't have Edge here to check it myself.